# Memoir Class, Madsen Style, Chapter Heading and Rule

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

I would like to extend the chapter title and the rule above it to the left, so it is -0.75 in past the text block.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{madsen}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}

Text

\chapter{Second chapter}

More text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Extend them to the left? Didn't you mean to the right? Let me see if I understand; you want the title and the rule to protrude `0.75in` from the outer (right) margin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following example I defined a `mymadsen` chapter style with the required specifications:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makechapterstyle{mymadsen}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{%
    \normalfont\large\scshape\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{%
    \normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \setlength{\chapindent}{0.75in}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{0.4em}%
      \resizebox{!}{4ex}{%
        \chapnamefont\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \chapnamefont \phantom{\printchaptername \chapternamenum%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{0.4em}%
        \resizebox{!}{4ex}{%
          \chapnamefont\bfseries\sffamily 10}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \setlength\midchapskip{1ex}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-\chapindent}{}
      \par\hrulefill\vskip\midchapskip
      \raggedleft \chaptitlefont ##1\par\nobreak
    \end{adjustwidth}}
}

\chapterstyle{mymadsen}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Test unnumbered chapter and some textv}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter{Test numbered chapter and some textviiii}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

An image for an unnumbered chapter:

[image]

and one for a numbered chapter:

[image]

Comment: This works, but I do need it to the left. Also, I need to keep the chapter name right aligned.

Comment: @RileyCooper What should exactly go to the left? with chapter name you mean the whole string "Chapter 1"? Excuse me but I am confused, so if you could explain in detail what should go where, I'd be thankful.

Comment: I do need the rule to be outdented on the left. The chapter name needs to retain its right alignment, but the width should be as long as the outdented rule. Also, in the image above the chapter number character needs to retain its placement off the right margin.

Comment: I'm going to use the whitespace under the outdented left rule for two levels of headings.

Comment: @RileyCooper please see my updated answer. Something like that?

Comment: @RileyCooper You can thank me by accepting the answer by clicking the check-mark to the left :-) In case of doubt, please see [`How do you accept an answer?`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).