# Move "chapter" and chapter number leftwards

Tags: numbering, positioning, chapters

I'm using the memoir class with the madsen style to write my thesis and I need help to move leftward the text "chapter" and the chapter number, in such a way that the right end of the number would coincide with the text margin. 
In other words I get this:

[image]

and I would like to obtain somethig like:

[image]

Comment: Please provide your (MWE) code.

Comment: Are you using the `Madsen` style?

Comment: I made use of the pure madsen style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A revamping of the `madsen` style:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makechapterstyle{gilgauge}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}%
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{%
    \normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedleft
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{%
    \normalfont\fontsize{24}{30}\bfseries\sffamily\raggedleft
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \hspace{0.4em}%
    {\chaptitlefont\thechapter}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \leavevmode\chapnamefont\vphantom{\chaptitlefont 1}%
    \afterchapternum
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{%
    \par\hspace{1.5cm}\hrule\vskip\midchapskip
  }%
}

\chapterstyle{gilgauge}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Conclusions and Perspectives for the Future}

\end{document}
```

I removed the small caps that seem out of place in an all sans serif context. Also scaling boxes can (and should) be avoided.

The “for the Future” bit is just for checking the output is right for a multiline title.

[image]

Comment: I decided to remodify your code in order to put the word "Chapter" in small caps again in the following way \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{%
  \normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft
 }

Comment: @gilgauge Just change `\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedleft` into `\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft`. But the result is far from being pretty; on the other hand, beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that gets the job done (change the `makebox` value) and is inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107630/121944) answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makechapterstyle{mymadsen}{% requires graphicx package
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{%
    \normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{%
    \normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \makebox[18pt][l]{\hspace{0.4em}% <--- altered makebox value
      \resizebox{!}{4ex}{%
        \chapnamefont\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \chapnamefont \phantom{\printchaptername \chapternamenum%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{0.4em}%
        \resizebox{!}{4ex}{%
          \chapnamefont\bfseries\sffamily 1}%
      }%
    }%
    \afterchapternum %
  }% 
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{%
    \par\hspace{1.5cm}\hrule\vskip\midchapskip}}

\chapterstyle{mymadsen}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Conclusions and Perspectives}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked "almost" fine for me. However, i would like to further move the whole towards left. Indeed, the number is by half beyond the margin (see https://ibb.co/cfW1Sy)

Comment: Just adjust the `makebox` that I pointed out. Change it to `20` or whatever works with your code.